# Mootools and YUI Carousel Issue

Tags: javascript, mootools, yui, carousel

I am working on a site which uses Mootools and a carousel has been added to the site which is taken from here - http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/carousel-ariaplugin_source.html

The problem is that the carousel somehow doesn't play nice with Mootools. With Mootools, it doesn't work and when I remove Mootools, it starts working. Firebug also doesn't show any JS errors or conflicts in console when Mootools is enabled.

I have setup couple of jsfiddles to demonstrate the issue.

- http://jsfiddle.net/jnED8/1/ (with mootools - DOES NOT WORK)
- http://jsfiddle.net/jnED8/ (without mootools - WORKS FINE)

**HTML**

```
<div class="yui-skin-sam">
        <h1 id="my-carousel-label">Expert Health Advice</h1>

    <div id="container">
        <ol id="carousel">
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/skintype/bio/leslie-baumann/"><img width="125" height="154" alt="Leslie Baumann, M.D." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/LeslieBaumann_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/skintype/bio/leslie-baumann/">Leslie Baumann, M.D.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/skintype/12135/skin-treatments-for-brides-to-be/">Skin Treatments for&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Thu 5.1.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/skintype/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/deepak/bio/deepak-chopra/"><img width="125" height="154" alt="Deepak Chopra, M.D." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/DeepakChopra_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/deepak/bio/deepak-chopra/">Deepak Chopra, M.D.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/deepak/2689/how-you-think-about-illness-affects-your-recovery/">How You Think About Illness&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Thu 5.1.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/deepak/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/nutrition/bio/christine-mckinney-nutrition/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Christine McKinney, M.S., R.D., C.D.E." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/ChristineMcKinney_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/nutrition/bio/christine-mckinney-nutrition/">Christine McKinney, M.S., R.D., C.D.E.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/nutrition/12067/fat-how-much-is-enough-of-a-good-thing/">Fat: How Much Is Enough of a&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Thu 5.1.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/nutrition/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/drmao/bio/maoshing-ni/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Dr. Maoshing Ni" src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/MaoshingNi_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/drmao/bio/maoshing-ni/">Dr. Maoshing Ni</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/drmao/13738/centenarian-tips-for-a-long-life/">Centenarian Tips for a Long&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Tue 4.29.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/drmao/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/breastcancer/bio/lillie-shockney/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Lillie Shockney, R.N., M.A.S." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/LillieShockney_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/breastcancer/bio/lillie-shockney/">
                    Lillie Shockney, R.N., M.A.S.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/breastcancer/5673/are-you-being-over-or-undertreated/">Are You Being Over- or&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Tue 4.29.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/breastcancer/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/depression/bio/david-neubauer/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="David Neubauer, M.D." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/DavidNeubauer_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/depression/bio/david-neubauer/">David Neubauer, M.D.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/depression/12445/could-a-breast-cancer-treatment-help-bipolar-disorder/">Could a Breast Cancer&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Tue 4.29.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/depression/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/capessa/bio/capessa/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Jennifer Tuma-Young" src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/Capessa_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/capessa/bio/capessa/">Jennifer Tuma-Young</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/capessa/3473/relieve-stress-with-your-senses/">Relieve Stress With Your&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Mon 4.28.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/capessa/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthieryou/bio/lucydanziger/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Lucy Danziger, SELF Edit" src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/LucyDanziger_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthieryou/bio/lucydanziger/">Lucy Danziger, SELF Edit</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthieryou/2639/de-stress-in-mere-minutes/">De-Stress in Mere Minutes</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Mon 4.28.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthieryou/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthnews/bio/simeon-margolis/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Simeon Margolis, M.D., Ph.D." src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/SimeonMargolis_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthnews/bio/simeon-margolis/">Simeon Margolis, M.D., Ph.D.</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthnews/13879/alzheimer-s-and-dementia-will-you-be-affected/">Alzheimer's and Dementia: Will&#8240;</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Mon 4.28.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/healthnews/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
            <li class="item">   <a title="View Author's Biography" class="authimg" href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/intentblog/bio/intentblog/"><img width="125" height="154" class="lz" alt="Mallika Chopra, IntentBlog" src="http://l.yimg.com/fz/ls/he/blogs/carousel/Intentblog_carousel.png"/></a>

                    <h3><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/intentblog/bio/intentblog/">Mallika Chopra, IntentBlog</a></h3>

                    <h4><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/intentblog/2919/treating-a-sore-throat/">Treating a Sore Throat</a></h4>
    <cite>Posted Mon 4.28.08</cite>

                <p class="all"><a href="http://health.yahoo.com/experts/intentblog/">View All Posts &#187;</a>

                </p>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload=function(){
(function () {
                var carousel;

                YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function (ev) {
                    var carousel = new YAHOO.widget.Carousel("container", {
                                animation: { speed: 0.5 },
                                describedby: "my-carousel-label"
                        });

                    carousel.render(); // get ready for rendering the widget
                    carousel.show();   // display the widget
                });
            })();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to use something built on Mootools. You could adapt this one that runs on Mootools 1.4 - http://jsfiddle.net/NfSLP/

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. However I would prefer to use the same carousel if possible.

Comment: Looking at your both fiddles.. It seems that the problem is with CSS... Use firebug to view both CSS stylings.. I am damm sure they are getting overidden..

Comment: I got this errors on examing fiddle with moootools on firebug: SyntaxError: illegal character
[Break On This Error]  

GIF89a

conversion.js (line 1, col 6)

SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://ww

combo?...-min.js (line 42)

Comment: @Shishir, I think the problem is that YUI is not very compatible with Mootools. Many methods have the same name and there are not much ways out.

Comment: @Sergio I guess then there is no way other than switching to a Mootools based carousel. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above, I think the best option is to use a Carousel based on Mootools.

**If that is the way you want to go, I contribute with this:**
(using your CSS files and layout)

### [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LjJp/)

CSS (extra, besides your files):

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: visible;
    position: relative;
    padding:0px;
    height:320px;
    width:10000px;
}
ol#carousel li.item {
    float: left;
    width:471px;
}
#container {
    height:400px;
    width:471px;
}
```

Mootools

```
var items = document.getElements('li.item');
var carousel = $('carousel');

/**************************************
Caroussel functions
**************************************/

var li_index = 0;

function gotoSlide(ind) {
    li_index = ind;
    var pos = items[ind].getPosition().x - carousel.getPosition().x;
    li_thumbs.each(function (e, i) {
        e.removeClass('yui-carousel-nav-page-selected');
        if (ind == i) e.addClass('yui-carousel-nav-page-selected');
    });
    carousel.morph({
        'margin-left': -pos
    });
};



/**************************************
Create rest of markup
**************************************/

var container = document.id('container');
container.addClass('yui-carousel-visible yui-carousel-horizontal yui-carousel');
var nav = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'yui-carousel-nav'
});
var li = new Element('li');
var ul = new Element('ul');
var span0 = new Element('span', {
    'class': 'yui-carousel-button'
});
var span1 = new Element('span', {
    'class': 'yui-carousel-button'
});
var btn = new Element('button');
var div_content = new Element('div', {
    'class': 'yui-carousel-content'
});

btn.clone().set('id', 'yui-gen10').inject(span0);
span0.addClass('yui-carousel-first-button').inject(nav);
btn.clone().set('id', 'yui-gen11').inject(span1);
span1.addClass('yui-carousel-next-button').inject(nav);

items.each(function (ele, ind) {
    li.clone().set('id', 'nav_button_' + ind).addEvent('click', function () {
        li_index = ind;
        gotoSlide(ind);
    }).inject(ul);
});
ul.getElement('li').addClass('yui-carousel-nav-page-selected');
ul.inject(nav);

div_content.inject(container);
nav.inject(container, 'top');
div_content.wraps(carousel);
document.getElements('.yui-carousel-button button').addEvent('click', function () {
    var ind = (this.id).split('yui-gen1')[1] == 0 ? li_index - 1 : li_index + 1;
    if (ind < 0 || ind > items.length - 1) return false;
    gotoSlide(ind);
});
var li_thumbs = $$('.yui-carousel-nav ul li');
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. It worked great, thanks for spending time on it and coming up with the required CSS and JS. Bounty is yours :)